# Split text using multiple delimiters into an array of trimmed values

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-split, csv

I've got a group of strings which I need to chunk into an array.
The string needs to be split on either `/`, `,`, `with`, or `&`.

Unfortunately it is possible for a string to contain two of the strings which needs to be split on, so I can't use `split()` or `explode()`.

For example, a string could say `first past/ going beyond & then turn`, so I am trying to get an array that would return:

```
array('first past', 'going beyond', 'then turn')
```

The code I am currently using is

```
$splittersArray=array('/', ',', ' with ','&');
foreach($splittersArray as $splitter){
    if(strpos($string, $splitter)){
        $splitString = split($splitter, $string);
        foreach($splitString as $split){
```

I can't seem to find a function in PHP that allows me to do this.
Do I need to be passing the string back into the top of the funnel, and continue to go through the `foreach()` after the string has been split again and again?

This doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: "Unfortunately it is possible for a string to contain two of the strings which needs to be split on, so I can't use split or explode." can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: I just added an example to clarify

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a regular expression and [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

In the case you mention, you would get the split array with:

```
$splitString = preg_split('/(\/|\,| with |\&/)/', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

To concisely write the pattern use a character class for the single-character delimiters and add the `with` delimiter as a value after the pipe (the "or" character in regex).  Allow zero or more spaces on either side of the group of delimiters so that the values in the output don't need to be trimmed.

I am using the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` function flag in case a delimiter occurs at the start or end of the string and you don't want to have any empty elements generated.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TdHPY))

```
$string = 'first past/ going beyond & then turn with everyone';

var_export(
    preg_split('~ ?([/,&]|with) ?~', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'first past',
  1 => 'going beyond',
  2 => 'then turn',
  3 => 'everyone',
)
```